# Titanium iOS module builds successfully but breaks in the test harness?

Tags: ios, module, titanium, i386

I have an iOS module built with Titanium mobilesdk 2.1.4.GA that relies on a handful of frameworks. The build.py command succeeds, but when I try to run the module in the module test harness, I get this error:

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MyNewViewController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libmy.module.a(MyModuleView.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386

If I don't use my added code, the module works great.

How can I build the correct version of my class for the test harness?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because I needed to add my class's files to "Copy Headers" and "Compile Sources" in Build Phases of my target. To fix, click the project name on the left, click the target in the list and the "Build Phases" tab. Then add the class's header and implementation files to "Copy Headers" and "Compile Sources".